# Not able to get the id of the group

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

```
if is_admin == True:
    admin_users = Group(name = 'Admin')
    try:
        admin_users.save()
    except:
        log.info("Admin Group already exists")
        pass
    group_id = Group.objects.get(name='Admin').id
```

If in the data that I get 'is_admin' is true then I will create the group 'Admin' if not existed then save it and fetches the id of that group-'Admin'. This id will be saved in the userinfo with Group as a foreign key.
   The following query should give me the id of that group.

```
group_id = Group.objects.get(name='admin').id 

 Instead it is saying

current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

I am using the postgresql database I don't know why it is giving me the error while executing this query. Please tell me how to write the query.

Comment: you need to reformat your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve is already in django: [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create). Using this your code should look like

```
group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Admin')
if created:
    log.info("Admin Group already exists")
group_id = group.pk
```

`pk` is a convenience property on all django models that always point to a primary key field, no matter if it's autocreated or specified explicitly.